# Reinitialize the end date of bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

> I am initializing the end date for my bootstrap datepicker :-

```
var endDate;
     endDate = Globalize.parseDate($("#txtStartDate").val())
     endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 29);
     $("#txtEndDate").attr("data-date-end-date", Globalize.format(endDate, 'd')); //setting end date for bootstrap date picker
```

> Then on change of start date,the end date should be reinitialized as
>   per      requirement but end date is not getting reinitialized.

```
 $("#txtStartDate").change(function() {
             var endDate = Globalize.parseDate($(this).val())
             endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 29);
             $("#txtEndDate").attr("data-date-end-date", Globalize.format(endDate, 'd')) //reinitializing the end date
         });
```

Comment: Add [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo example

Comment: Hi Sarjan,
The only thing is that second time attrbute change does not get reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
$("#txtStartDate").on('changeDate', function () {
         var endDate = Globalize.parseDate($(this).val())
         endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 29);
         $("#txtEndDate").attr("data-date-end-date", Globalize.format(endDate, 'd')) //reinitializing the end date
     });
```